# ウィンドウズで、今入力されたキースキャンコードを表示するには？

Tags: windows

Windows 7 を利用しています。
レジストリをいじってキーの入れ替えを行おうとしています。
このためには、入れ替えたいキーのスキャンコードを知っておく必要がありますが、
今入力したキーを表示するような機能 (方法) はありますか？

できれば、追加ソフト(よくわからないソフト)はインストールしないほうが望ましいです。
もし追加ソフトが必要なら、ソースが公開されているもののほうが望ましいです。
(セキュリティ的な観点で)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows の標準コマンドだけで調べる方法を真剣にネタ回答してみます。

IBM/PC というか PS/2 互換機の 16bit BIOS を呼び出してみましょう。
(NEC PC98 は考慮しません)
(実際に動くのは 32bit Windows 内部の BIOS シミュレータですけど)

キースキャンコードは PC-BIOS コール `INT 16H` `AH=10H` で取得できますから
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_16H
32bit Windows (Windows 7/XP では確認済み Windows 8 32bit は手元に無いので未確認) なら
コマンドプロンプトから `debug.exe` を起動してハンドアセンブル入力しましょう。
`debug.exe` の `a` はアセンブル `g` は実行 `q` は終了コマンドです。

```
C>debug
-a
351B:0100 MOV AH,10
351B:0102 INT 16
351B:0104 INT 3
351B:0105 <Enter> のみ
-g
```

ここでキー入力待ちになるので調べたいキーを押します。 ESC キーを押してみました。

```
AX=011B  BX=0000  CX=0000  DX=0000  SP=FFEE  BP=0000  SI=0000  DI=0000
DS=351B  ES=351B  SS=351B  CS=351B  IP=0104   NV UP EI PL NZ NA PO NC
351B:0104 CC            INT     3
-q
C>
```

`AH=01` がスキャンコード `AL=1B` がキーコード (ASCII) です。

複数回実行したかったら `q` せずに `g=100` でもう一度実行できます。

64bit Windows は 16bit code を実行できないのでこの方法は使えません。
既にレジストリでキーマップを入れ替えていると、
この方法で得たコードは入れ替えた後のコードになっています。
[窓] キーなど Windows 内部で処理が完結するキーのコードは調査しようがありません。
実用度は低いです（まあネタですし）。

Answer (score 1):

追加ソフトでソースが公開されている例を挙げれば、AutoHotKeyがあります。
Download - Other versionのページにBinaries(インストーラーでないもの)もあり、適当なディレクトリに解凍して、使い終わったらディレクトリごと消すこともできます。

https://autohotkey.com/
https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey

AutoHotKeyでのスキャンコードの調べ方についてわかりやすいページがなかったため、最も簡単と思われる手順を書きます。

1. AutoHotKey.exeを解凍したディレクトリに`AutoHotKey.ahk`ファイルを作成
2. 作成したファイルをエディタで開き、`#InstallKeybdHook`の1行を追記して保存
3. AutoHotKey.exeを起動後、タスクトレイアイコンを右クリックして`Open`を選択
4. メニューの`[View] - [Key history and script info]`を選択
5. 調べたいキーを押下した後、F5を押すと入力したキーの情報が画面に表示されます

SCの列に表示されるものがScan Codeです。